# My Display Won't Work

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, display

I have a [5" Touchscreen display from SainSmart](http://www.sainsmart.com/5-inch-800x480-hdmi-touch-lcd-screen-display-for-raspberry-pi-pi2-model-b-a.html), and I can't use the full screen, or even the touch screen. I have done everything that I could find to fix it. I have adjusted the overscan settings, forced the console size to be 800x480, and tried disabling overscan.
My current concern is making the screen work, but if anyone knows how to get the touch screen working, I would appreciate it.
It is connected by hdmi and the Little pins on the raspberry.

[image: screen]

I am using a raspberry pi 3. I used Noobs to set it up.

Comment: @goldilocks How do I upload an image? (I'm using the mobile app)

Comment: The normal edit interface has a little icon with (triangle) mountains in a frame, along the top of the text box, for uploading an image.  TBH I don't use the mobile app except to read stuff occasionally so I am not sure how similar it is.  There must be something though.

Comment: The comment on the product page that support for the 2 is "coming soon" doesn't bode well if you are using a 3... Unfortunately I think a lot of people get suckered into buying the cheapest "For the Raspberry Pi!" touchscreen they can find figuring they can make it work, then they can't.

Comment: What kind of output do you see on the screen when connected and with the Pi booted up?

Comment: @MohammadAli The Pi outputs video as if it is a fullscreen display. Next to it, there is just black with a bunch of purple lines.

Comment: Can I have a photo?

Comment: @MohammadAli The photo is in the place of the old one.

Comment: Are you connected to the pi via the gpio pins or by the hdmi port, and have you tried both options?

Comment: @MohammadAli Both. The pins only seem to power the screen, the hdmi sends the video signal.

Comment: have you installed the proprietary drivers mentioned on their site?

Comment: @MohammadAli There are no links, and there was nothing with the screen that said where to get them.

Comment: I've written an answer tell me how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem you are facing is because the pi is not recognizing your display as the resolution that it is and I'm going to walk you through manually setting that resolution.

1. We are going to start by turning off the pi and placing the sd card into a computer.
2. We are now going to locate a file named `config.txt` on the sd card, if you find it open it if you do not please leave a comment for help
3. we want to enter the following into the file:

   ```
   hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6
   hdmi_group=2
   hdmi_mode=87
   hdmi_drive=2
   ```
4. we want to save and close this file
5. boot the pi share a photo if it does not work.

NOTE: you may have to revert changes to your overscan settings any any other changes you may have made

Comment: The full screen is now being utilized! Thank you very much!

Comment: @RueLyfe Not a problem. Be sure to like as well if my answer has helped you

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation. :(

Comment: @RueLyfe oh i didn't notice, fell free to check back after you've gained some points, Hope you are enjoying the site